# Powershell O365 Nested DLs - Add AcceptMessagesOnly From

Tags: powershell

We currently have a short script in Powershell that will amend our nested DLs. They currently take the top DL and add users to the AcceptOnlyMessagesFrom part. Previously there was only one level of nesting and now they've been amended so they're nested multiple times. How would I go about modifying this script to loop it so it goes all the way down?

```
$DistributionList = "MainDistributionList"
$Members = "Email1","Email2"
$DLs = Get-DistributionGroupMember $DistributionList | Select-Object DisplayName
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $DistributionList -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom @{Add=$Members}
ForEach ($DL in $DLs) {Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $DL.DisplayName | Set-DistributionGroup -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom @{Add=$Members}}
```

***Edit***

So I managed to come up with a way to do it but not really how I'd like it because it's not a proper loop I've just written them all out manually as to how many nested levels we have. It will do for now though and is a hell of a lot easier/quicker than doing it manually. Teach me Powershell gurus!

```
$DistributionList = "ParentDL"
$Members = "Email1","Email2"
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $DistributionList -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom @{Add=$Members}
$Nested1DLs = Get-DistributionGroupMember $DistributionList | Select-Object DisplayName
$Nested2DLs = Foreach ($DL in $Nested1DLs) {Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DL.DisplayName | Select-Object DisplayName,RecipientType | Where-Object {$_.RecipientType -like "MailUniversalDistributionGroup"}}
$Nested3DLs = Foreach ($DL in $Nested2DLs) {Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DL.DisplayName | Select-Object DisplayName,RecipientType | Where-Object {$_.RecipientType -like "MailUniversalDistributionGroup"}}
ForEach ($DL in $Nested1DLs) {Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $DL.DisplayName | Set-DistributionGroup -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom @{Add=$Members}}
ForEach ($DL in $Nested2DLs) {Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $DL.DisplayName | Set-DistributionGroup -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom @{Add=$Members}}
ForEach ($DL in $Nested3DLs) {Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $DL.DisplayName | Set-DistributionGroup -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom @{Add=$Members}}
```

Comment: You would write a recursive function.  A recursive function calls itself.

Comment: So, just to clarify, the members of the top level distribution list should be the only users that are able to email that list and all nested distribution lists beneath it? If members are removed from the top level list, should they also be automatically removed in the same fashion? Are there any additional users that will be set manually? That is, should those top level members always be the single source of truth?

Comment: Yes, this is used by our comms department so we have a set list of users that can send to this "All Company" DL. Now the DL is made up of our divisional DLs which some are further split up to regional DLs so the comms team can email divisions/regions if they need to. At the minute it's always the same list of users that can email all of them. Not really worried about removing them at the minute because I don't think that will come up. We could potentially have manually added people able to email regions so may not always be the same as the parent. Hope that clears it up a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script. The first 3 variables are for you to set:

### Variables

1. `$WhatIf`: See what the script is going to do before making any changes. Set to `$false` when you're ready to make those changes.
2. `$TopGroup`: The topmost group containing nested groups. `AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom` is derived from direct members residing here.
3. `$OverwriteAcceptMessagesOnlyFrom`: If `$true`, `AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom` will be overwritten, if `$false`, it'll be appended to (see script output). You should set this to `$false` if you have existing users you'd like to keep or plan on adding some manually in the future.

### Script

```
$WhatIf = $true
$TopGroup = "dltest1@example.org"
$OverwriteAcceptMessagesOnlyFrom = $true

function Get-DistributionGroupRecursive {
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)][string[]]$Identity,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, DontShow)][string[]]$LastResults,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, DontShow)][switch]$ChildSearch = $false
  )

  $Condition = { $_.RecipientType -eq "MailUniversalDistributionGroup" -and $LastResults -notcontains $_ }
  $Identity | ForEach-Object {
    if ($ChildSearch) {
      $Results = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_ -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object $Condition | Get-DistributionGroup
    } else {
      $Results = Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $_ -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object $Condition
    }
    if (($Results | Measure-Object).Count -gt 0) {
      $Results
      Get-DistributionGroupRecursive -Identity $Results.Name -LastResults ($LastResults + $Results.Name) -ChildSearch
    }
  }
}

$TargetGroups = Get-DistributionGroupRecursive $TopGroup
Write-Host "Target distribution groups will be:"
$TargetGroups | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host "  - $($_.PrimarySmtpAddress)"
}

$TopGroupMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $TopGroup | Where-Object { $_.RecipientType -eq "UserMailbox" }
Write-Host "`r`nAcceptMessagesOnlyFrom will be:"
$TopGroupMembers | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host "  - $($_.PrimarySmtpAddress)"
}

if ($OverwriteAcceptMessagesOnlyFrom) {
  Write-Host "`r`nAcceptMessagesOnlyFrom will be overwritten. Any existing or manually added entries will be deleted!`r`n"
  $TargetGroups | Set-DistributionGroup -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom $TopGroupMembers.Name -WhatIf:$WhatIf
} else {
  Write-Host "`r`nAcceptMessagesOnlyFrom will be appended to. Members removed from top group in the future will need to be manually removed from nested groups' AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom!`r`n"
  $TargetGroups | Set-DistributionGroup -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom @{ Add = $TopGroupMembers.Name } -WhatIf:$WhatIf
}
```

### Example output

In this example run, we have some groups nested within others. *topdog1* and *topdog2* are members of *dltest1*, so they become the exclusive users able to email all target groups.

```
Target distribution groups will be:
  - dltest1@example.org
  - dltest2@example.org
  - dltest3@example.org
  - dltest4@example.org
  - dltest5@example.org

AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom will be:
  - topdog1@example.org
  - topdog2@example.org

AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom will be overwritten. Any existing or manually added entries will be deleted!

What if: Setting distribution group Identity:"DLTest120210618024157".
What if: Setting distribution group Identity:"DLTest220210618024235".
What if: Setting distribution group Identity:"DLTest320210618024254".
What if: Setting distribution group Identity:"DLTest420210618055828".
What if: Setting distribution group Identity:"DLTest520210621111355".
```